# Firefox is not keeping css style on selected menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have only tested this is firefox and chrome, but so far I have not been able to get the style to correctly work on firefox

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div style="" class="navbar-collapse collapse in">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

and the style is

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:active 
{
color: #9DE0AD !important;
}
```

I think its a problem with bootstrap overwriting a style at some point

For example if I clicked on the about menu then move my mouse off it then the text is the wrong colour

here is an example site of it

(free host (sorry)) : http://free-world.site40.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rule in your bootstrap.css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
background-color: transparent;
color: #333;
}
```

Please try to make an override using:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
color: #9de0ad !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! bootstrap makes everything 100% more complicated but 100% better :D

Any reason why it worked in chrome without this?

Comment: There is a focus event that chrome don't catch. You could remove line 37 from style.css to make both browser work properly.